# Flex container with flex-direction column-reverse will not scroll to top

Tags: javascript, flexbox, scrolltop

I am displaying notifications in the following *[div](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Other_block_elements)* in order to show the last elements at the top of the container:

```html
<div class="flex h-full max-h-full pt-36">
    <div id="scrollDiv" class="justify-bottom z-20 flex w-full flex-col-reverse items-center overflow-y-scroll scrollbar-thin">
        <div class="notification"></div>
        <div class="notification"></div>
        <div class="notification"></div>
        <div class="notification"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Automatically, when the container overflows, it is scrolled to the bottom. I have tried to set `scrollTop` using the following Javascript without any success:

```js
function scrollNotifications() {
    var element = document.getElementById('scrollDiv')
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight
}
```

How can I scroll the container to the top when overflowing on the y axis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was with the `scrollTop` positioning. The 0 value will scroll to the bottom because of the reverse direction property. The simple trick was to set a negative value:

```js
function scrollNotifications() {
    var element = document.getElementById('scrollDiv')
    element.scrollTop = -element.scrollHeight
}
```

Comment: To add to this - if you need to scroll to a specific position instead of just the top, you need to offset by the client height of the element. So for example of 80 pixels from "top":

`elenent.scroll({ top: (element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight - 80) * -1 });`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect scroll to the top here is a solution:

```
var element = document.getElementById('scrollDiv');
var elementHeight = element.scrollHeight - 1;

// Adding a scroll event listener to the element
element.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var currentPosition = element.clientHeight - element.scrollTop;
    if(elementHeight === currentPosition){
        console.log("reached top");
    }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Was this generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)?

Comment: No this is not generated by ChatGPT!